# WPF event handler in ItemContainerStyle

Tags: c#, wpf

I have DataGrid

```
<DataGrid x:Name="EFDataGrid"
          Visibility="Hidden"
          AutoGenerateColumns="False"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ExchangeFile}"
          SelectionMode="Single"
          CanUserAddRows="False"
          CanUserDeleteRows="False"
          CanUserReorderColumns="False"
          CanUserResizeRows="False"
          CanUserSortColumns="False">
    <DataGrid.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
            <EventSetter Event="MouseRightButtonDown"
                         Handler="Row_MouseRightButtonDown" />
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.ItemContainerStyle>
    <DataGrid.Columns>some columns</DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

and this handler in code behind

```
private void Row_MouseRightButtonDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    some methods
}
```

but when I do right click on a row nothing going, event handler does not executes.

What I do wrong?

Is there another way to handle this event(Right click on a row)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by using `RowStyle` instead of `ItemContainerStyle`:

```
<DataGrid.RowStyle>
    <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
        <EventSetter Event="MouseRightButtonDown" Handler="Row_MouseRightButtonDown" />
    </Style>
</DataGrid.RowStyle>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
void Row_MouseRightButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    some methods
}
```

You worte  *MouseEventArgs e* instead of *MouseButtonEventArgs e*. Is that a typo? If not, use MouseButtonEventArgs instead.

MouseEventArgs is used for MouseLeave, MouseMove etc. 
MouseButtonEventArgs is used for MouseRightButtonDown, MouseRightButtonUp etc.

Comment: i tryed differend EventArgs(Routed, Mouse, MouseButton etc.) no changes, looks like that event doest generates

Answer (score 0):

I think you need `RoutedEventArgs` instead of `MouseEventArgs`

```
private void Row_MouseRightButtonDown(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    //Some Method
}
```

and you should create the event on `DataCell` instead of `DataGridRow`

```
<Style TargetType="EFDataGrid:DataCell">
    <EventSetter Event="MouseRightButtonDown" Handler="Row_MouseRightButtonDown"/>
</Style>
```

You can also create an **attached behavior** for right clicking

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

```
 <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding ...}">
            <DataGrid.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
                    <EventSetter Event="MouseRightButtonDown" Handler="Row_MouseRightButtonDown"/>
                </Style>
            </DataGrid.Resources>
        </DataGrid>
```

Than you don't need the ItemContainerStyle

Comment: Replace the `Event="MouseRightButtonDown"` with `Event="PreviewMouseRightButtonDown"`

Comment: Nothing changes again event still not starts, maybe i should use anothet target type?

Comment: Can you show me your model-class for `ExchangeFile`

Answer (score 0):

use RoutedEventArgs as mentioned above!

```
   private void Row_MouseRightButtonDow(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    do stuff
}
```

Comment: I tryed use RoutedEvenArgs, but nothing changes

Comment: check out [this](http://wpf.2000things.com/tag/routedeventargs/). i hope this will clarify some basics